# Jack's vs Jacks for "Jack his phone"

Tags: writing

I am non-native in English so forgive me if this question is too low level.

If you are talking about something that belongs to a person you can say "Jacks phone" to mean "the phone of Jack", at least, that is how I pronounce it. However, in writing it could also be "Jack's phone" and you wouldn't notice anything different in the pronunciation. So which one is correct?

I thought the first one, because I would say that the second would actually mean "Jack is phone" (which obviously makes no sense), but as a counterexample I can find many diners that are called ["...'s diner"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%27s%20diner) which are clearly meant as "The diner of ...".

Therefore my question is: which is correct? and what is the rule? Should you recognize the meaning of 's for "is" or "his" from the context?

Comment: Good question. There are rules, but they are complex and have lots of exceptions, especially in writing. Luckily, you're writing here about talking, and that's much more sensible.

Comment: Based on your opening sentence, I'm guessing you might have asked this question on [ell.se], had you been aware of that site's existence. And I think you're referring to **Jack's phone**, using an apostrophe to indicate the possessive form.

Comment: @J.R. yes, indeed I would have. Although I am unsure whether this is the level of English Language Learners or something that even native speakers might not be aware of (which would make it more suitable for this site I presume).

Comment: If people think this question would be more appropriate for English Languange Learners then please upvote this comment and I will flag for migration.

Comment: I think your presumption is right - the dividing line would be where you're asking about something "even native speakers might not be aware of." I would recommend leaving this question here, but at least you know about the other site for your next question, and you can do your best to figure out where it would be best asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to go ahead and presume by your name and location that Dutch is your native language.

#### Writing

Unlike in Dutch, where the possessive is formed in writing simply by adding *-s* to the noun phrase where possible, modern English orthography requires that there always be an apostrophe present in the possessive.

Therefore, *Jack’s coat* is the only correct way to write this.

*’s* is also, as you say, a contraction of *is* and *has*. When you see something like *Jack’s* written, you have to rely on the context to know whether it means ‘… belonging to Jack’, ‘Jack is’, or ‘Jack has’:

> Jack’s coat *(possessive)*
>   Jack’s a coat *(‘is’—and an odd phrase)*
>   Jack’s got a coat *(‘has’)*
>   That Michael’s got Jack’s coat’s strange *(‘has’ – possessive – ‘is’, in that order)*

When the version without the apostrophe, *-s*, is added to a noun, it always forms plurals, and nothing else; so *Jacks* means ‘several copies of Jack’ (again, this is the opposite of Dutch, where most nouns take *-s* in the plural, but those that end in a long vowel take *’s*):

> There are two Jacks in our class

In other words, your example of *Jacks phone* does not work in English writing at all. It does not establish any kind of connection between the two noun phrases—it is equivalent to saying *women phone*, or in Dutch, *vrouwen telefoon*.

So much for writing.

#### Speech

It’s much simpler (yet much more complex) in speech. As John Lawler and Barrie England have both mentioned, and as you yourself said also, there is no difference in the pronunciation of *-s* and *’s* (just as in Dutch).

In other words, the following two phrases (the first orthographically correct, the second orthographically nonsensical) are pronounced exactly the same:

> That Michael’s got Jack’s coat’s strange
>   That Michaels got Jacks coats strange

*Only* the grammatical, intonational, and syntactical context enables you to tell which is which.

#### ‘His’

It should be mentioned at the end here that the possessive clitic *’s* does not have anything to do with the possessive adjective/pronoun *his*.

It is fairly common in the Germanic languages to create periphrastic genitives by using the possessing noun phrase in whatever case syntax prescribes for it and then simply tacking on a ‘his/her/their’ to link it to the possessed noun phrase:

> *Mannen sin hatt* (Norwegian)
>   *Der Mann sein Hut* (German)
>   *De man zijn hoed* (Dutch)

This, however, is **not** the origin of the English possessive in *’s* came about. The possessive is simply a reinterpreted, simplified, and worn-down version of the old case ending *-es*, just like in Dutch.

Comment: Nicely written and quite clear.  However, it's not true that "Jacks phone" or "women phone" have no meaning - *phone* can be used as a verb, meaning "to call someone by telephone".  So "The two Jacks phone each other every weekend" is a perfectly valid, if slightly slangy, sentence.  You could also say "Women phone me up all the time" if you were so inclined.

Comment: The opposite uses in Dutch and English are most likely the main reason for my confusion so it is great to see an answer explaining how it works. Thanks!

Comment: @MT_Head: I deliberately didn't include alternative grammatical analyses so as to keep things simple. I dealt only with noun phrases (and tried to say so indirectly by referring to noun phrases repeatedly). The examples from the other Germanic languages are unambiguous, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Your last sentence is absolutely right. You understand what is being said from the context. That is true of this point and of many others.